# add this php code inside this javascript

Tags: php, javascript

can someone tell me how to add this php code:

```
<?php  include('shopping_cart_temp.php'); ?>
```

Into this javascript line:

```
$('.cart_status').append('<p class="json-productname">' + retObj.product_name );
```

Comment: Why can't the line be inserted straight into the PHP?

Comment: This won't work because you're using object values, no where have you specified where this data has came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifically,

```
$.get('shopping_car_temp.php', function(result){
   $('.cart_status').append('<p class="json-productname">' + result );
});
```

In your shopping_car_temp.php file, echo only retObj.product_name. If you need to echo multiple things, you may want to format them as JSON objects. You can read about those at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: sorry I only just noticed you had also provided the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use an AJAX call:

```
$.get('shopping_car_temp.php', function(result){
    // display the data returned, value store in 'result'
});
```

Comment: i tried this:

      `$('.cart_status').html('Added to cart :');
  $('.cart_status').append('<p class="json-productname">' + retObj.product_name                  );
  $.get('shopping_car_temp.php', function(result){
                 // display the data returned, value store in 'result'
    });
  
    if (retObj.options != '')`
  {

and it didnt work

Comment: Can't see the entire code you posted - but make sure that you're jQuery is right - $.get sends a asynchronous call to that page, and result is the value that the page returns (after running PHP, result = the HTML).

Comment: sorry im a complete newbie to jQuery and dont understand where im supposed to add your code? 

I tried this but the shopping_cart_temp.php contents dont show:

`$('.cart_status').append('<php echo(shopping_cart_temp.php); ?>');
$('.cart_status').append('<p class="json-productname">' + retObj.product_name );
  if (retObj.options != '')
  {`

Comment: Okay okay, post your code on pastebin.com and send the link here lol it keeps chopping it off. Anyways, wherever you want the result HTML from the PHP page to show is where you append it to. So if you are using that PHP file as a webpage template, you would use $('body').append(result);

Comment: Ok this script uses 3 files in total, 2 php files and a js file. It creates a popup when you click on an add to cart button, and shows the added item in the new popup window
I'm trying to modify the code to show the contents of my shopping_cart_temp.php file inside the popup

Here is php file number 1, ProductObject: [link](http://pastebin.com/uE3cw7Ai)

Here is php file number 2, Actions:  [link](http://pastebin.com/dJq0PGks)

And here is the js file, osc cart: [link](http://pastebin.com/GYm7UBzX)

hope this works

Comment: $.get('shopping_car_temp.php', function(result){  $('.cart_status').append('<p class="json-productname">' + result ); }); -- Use that to place the content of that PHP page inside the <p> tag, just make sure that the <p> tag is ended or it won't show up.

Comment: Awesome! works great, thanks a lot! I would have spent hours/days and never got it.

Comment: can I ask for your help with something else pls? (with the same script)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, while Javascript is a client side language.
When you request a php page in your browser the request is processed by the server, PHP code is interpreted and an HTML page is sent to you. Then, only when HTML page is in your browser, javascript is interpreted, so from here you can't add PHP code because it couldn't be interpreted.

As @TurdPile said, you can make an ajax request to get the code from shopping_cart_temp.php and then manipulate it, but you should read some ajax tutorial to understand exactly how it works because it could be quite hard to understand

Comment: thanks for this, now I have a basic understanding of how JavaScript works.